# Algoritmo rango de vision en javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

espero me puedan ayudar con este algoritmo:
dado un numero entero por ejemplo 342213

el algoritmo trata del rango de visión de los números, es decir el primer número de izquierda a derecha (3) solo puede ver tres posiciones a la derecha y tres posiciones a la izquierda, en este caso el (3) solo puede ver al 4 al 2 y el otro 2, ya que a la izquierda no hay números.
El numero (4) puede ver cuatro posiciones a la derecha y cuatro a la izquierda. osea puede ver al 2, 2, 1, 3 y puede ver al 3 a la izquierda.

explicado lo anterior

```
3 puede ver 4 2 2 entonces 4+2+2=8
4 puede ver 2 2 1 3 entonces 2+2+1+3=8 y a la izquierda 3 8+3= 11
2 puede ver 2 1 entonces 2+1 = 3 y a la izquierda 3,4 3+4+3=10
2 puede ver 1 3 entonces 1+3 = 4 y a la izquierda 2,4 2+4+4=10
1 puede ver 3 a la derecha y a la izquierda 2 entonces 3+2=5
3 puede ver solo a la izquierda 1 + 2 + 2 = 5
```

la funcion debe retornar true si hay un rango de vision menor que compartan 2 numeros en este caso si hay, el 1 y el 3 regresan 5.

Ya supe por donde empezar xD.

Llevo esto

```
const rangeViewNumber = (num) => {

  let arreglo = num.toString().split('').map(numero => 
  Number(numero))
  let valor = []
  let suma = 0

  for(let i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){

      if(arreglo[i-1] === undefined){
          let z = arreglo[i]
          for(let x=1; x <= z; x++){
              suma+=arreglo[x]
          }
          valor.push(suma)
          suma=0
      }else if(arreglo[i+1] === undefined){
          let z = arreglo[i]
          for(let c = arreglo.length-1; c >= 0; c--){
              z--
              if(z>=0){
                  suma+=arreglo[c-1]
              }  
          }
          valor.push(suma)
          suma=0
      }
  }
  console.log(valor)
}

rangeViewNumber(1234232)
```

Answer (score 1):

listo, mas de 14 horas trabajando, sip, para algo tan sencillo...

```
const rangeViewNumber = (num) => {

    let arreglo = num.toString().split('').map(numero => Number(numero))
    console.log(arreglo)
    let valor = []
    let suma = 0
    let menor = 0
    let repite = 0;

    for(let i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){

        if(arreglo[i-1] === undefined){
            let z = arreglo[i]
            for(let x=1; x <= z; x++){
                suma+=arreglo[x]
            }
            valor.push(suma)
            suma=0
        }else if(arreglo[i+1] === undefined){
            let z = arreglo[i]
            for(let c = arreglo.length-1; c >= 0; c--){
                z--
                if(z>=0){
                    suma+=arreglo[c-1]
                }
            }
            valor.push(suma)
            suma=0
        }
        else{
            let z = arreglo[i]
            for(let y=i;y<=arreglo.length;y++){
                z--
                if(z>=0 && arreglo[y+1]!== undefined){
                    suma+=arreglo[y+1]
                }
            }
            let w = arreglo[i]
            for(let y=i;y>=0;y--){
                w--
                if(w>=0 && arreglo[y-1]!== undefined){
                    suma+= arreglo[y-1]
                }
            }
            valor.push(suma)
            suma=0
        }
    }
    console.table(valor)

    for(let cont=0;cont<valor.length;cont++){
        if(valor[cont+1]< valor[cont]){
            menor = valor[cont+1]
        }
    }
    for(let cont=0;cont<valor.length;cont++){
        if(valor[cont] === menor){
            repite+=1
        }
    }
    if(repite>=2)
    return true
    console.log(repite)
}

console.log(rangeViewNumber(342213))
```

Comment: No olvides explicar _cómo funciona este código_. La pregunta y su respuesta deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar. Lee [answer], [ask], y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.